# Palindromes using Stacks and Queues

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, queue

My NEW sample text i was testing: My mom is a good cook. Although sometimes at around noon she will leave and forget to make me lunch and some pop.  @Old homework become relevant again

my problem is just that i am not getting the correct output, as my method only prints *Mom a noon i

This is all GUI based.I am reading in a file and checking for palindromes and printing them out in my JTextArea afterwards using Stacks and Queue's.

Issue is, all of this is working and when i start the program and attach the text file, i only get the first palindrome. SO it will print "mom" which is my first testcase, but it won't go to any of the other palindromes following it?

I thought i might have got bogged down in my code blocking at some point but after tinkering with it for a day now i'm sort of stuck.

EDIT 1: I am now getting more results

my method is,

```
public void fileDecode() throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        if (fileChoice.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            file = fileChoice.getSelectedFile();

            scanInput = new Scanner(file);

            while(scanInput.hasNext())
            {

                int nextPalindrome = 0;
                int counter = 0;
                String token = scanInput.next();
                Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<Character>();
                Queue<Character> que = new LinkedList<Character>();
                for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); ++i)
                {
                    stk.push(token.charAt(i));  //pushing all char's onto the stack/queue
                    que.add(token.charAt(i));

                }
                for (int j = 0; j < token.length(); ++j)
                {
                        char tempStk = stk.pop(); //removing them one at a time and checking if they are equal and incrementing counter
                        char tempQue = que.remove();

                        if (tempStk == tempQue)
                        {
                            counter++;
                        }
                }

                if (counter == token.length())
                {
                   build.append(token + " "); //if the counter # was the same as the token's length, than it is indeed a palindrome and we append it into our StringBuilder that we pass to the JTextArea
                   nextPalindrome = token.length();
                } 
            }  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set counter to 0 outside your while loop, so the count of the second word is going to start at the count of the first word. Move `counter = 0` inside the while loop and it should work.

Also, nextPalindrome doesn't appear to be used, and even if it is, if you set it at the bottom of the loop, it's immediately set to 0 at the top, so it will only remain non-zero if the last word is a palindrome.

Also, think about what's happening in the second `for` loop. You're looping over all the characters and comparing the one from the stack and the one from the queue. If ever those are different, you know you don't have a palindrome, so once you find a difference, it's pointless to continue with the loop. You also already have a loop counter, `j`, so you don't need another one. So I'd rewrite the second loop and following condition as follows:

```
            for (int j = 0; j < token.length(); ++j)
            {
                    char tempStk = stk.pop(); //removing them one at a time and checking if they are equal and incrementing counter
                    char tempQue = que.remove();

                    if (tempStk != tempQue)
                        break;
            }

            if (j == token.length())
```

That works because the only way `j` can equal `token.length()` after the loop is done is if the loop completed, which can only happen if no pairs of characters aren't equal (in other words, all pairs of characters are equal, which is what you want).

Comment: Moving it inside the while loop did indeed yield me more results. I now however, an getting things printed like, `i` and `a` along with the real palindromes `noon` and `mom`, which i know i have to go in and make more conditions. Could you explain your third message again? the removing the second for loop part.

Comment: and as a side note, the nextPalindrome variable is because i need to do something like, `mom` is a palindrome and `length()` is equal to 3. So you would grab the third token away from `mom` and that would be a part of the secret message, just havent got that far yet haha

Comment: Well, `i` and `a` are palindromes. :-) But yeah, if you don't want those, just check for `token.length() == 1` and loop. I'll edit my answer to expand on my last paragraph.

Comment: @SenjuXo Ok, expanded on my third paragraph.

Comment: thanks! @blm i've gotten everything working now. All i have now is to figure out how to take the palindromes length and then print the token at that length like i mentioned in my side note, second comment.